# Prove that $G \times H$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $G \times H = \{(x, y): x \in G \text { and } y \in H\}.$
>
> The operation on $G \times H: (x, y) \cdot (x', y') = (xx', yy').$

$(x_1, y_1)[(x_2, y_2)(x_3, y_3)] = (x_1, y_1)(x_2x_3, y_2y_3) = (x_1x_2x_3, y_1y_2y_3).$

$[(x_1, y_1)(x_2, y_2)](x_3, y_3) = (x_1x_2, y_1y_2)(x_3, y_3) = (x_1x_2x_3, y_1y_2y_3).$

$G \times H $ is associative.

Let $e_G $ and $e_H$ be the identity elements of $G$ and $H$ respectively. Then $e_{G \times H} = (e, e)$ is an identity element of $G \times H$ since $(xx', yy')(e, e) = (xx', yy')$ and $(e, e)(xx', yy') = (xx', yy')$.

Let $(a, b) \in G \times H.$ Then $(a^{-1}, b^{-1})$ is the inverse of $(a, b)$ since $(a, b)(a^{-1}, b^{-1}) = (a^{-1}, b^{-1})(a, b) = (e, e).$

---

Please, check my work.

Comment: Presumably, $G,H$ are already known to be groups? It's always important to state your assumptions.

Comment: I don't get why you write $xx^\prime$ and $yy^\prime$ for the checking the identity element. I would simply write $(e, e)(x, y) = (ex, ey) = (x, y)$.

Comment: $G, H$ are groups. $G \times H$ is their direct product.

Comment: You should be more careful ont the associative law: $$(x_1x_2,y_1y_2)(x_3,y_3)=((x_1x_2)x_3,(y_1y_2)y_3)=(x_1(x_2x_3),y_1(y_2y_3))$$

Comment: @ George V. Williams, I see.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews, if you don't mind, what's the reason for that?

Comment: @Marko When you just write $x_1x_2x_3$ then it's a slight abuse of notation, because when you write it you apparently don't care if it means $(x_1x_2)x_3$ or $x_1(x_2x_3)$. If you are trying that the latter two are equal, you have to care about parentheses.

Comment: For the identity: you need to show $$(e,e)(x,y)=(ex,ey)=(x,y)$$ and $$(x,y)(e,e)=(xe,ye)=(x,y)$$ George's way is correct but then you would need to show the commutative law if not, you must show both ways.